# Help setting up MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, schema

I need help setting up my MySQL Database.

I would like the database to have a table called accounts. All user accounts would be kept in that database. The user account would have the keys:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address
- Username
- Password
- Date of Last Login.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what the schema should look like for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE  `MyDatabase`.`accounts` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`FirstName` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`LastName` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`Email` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
`Username` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`Password` CHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`LastLoginDate` DATE NOT NULL
)
```

This assumes you're using an MD5 hashed password (which is 32 in length).  Replace MyDatabase with your database name.

Comment: So do you need to create a new table for each user?

Comment: No to add a user you would use the MySQL "INSERT INTO" syntax. Like: INSERT INTO accounts (FirstName, LastName, Email, Username, Password, LastLoginDate) VALUES ("John", "Smith", "Jsmith@gmail.com", "jsmith", "jsmithpasswordhash", "date")

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. One more thing for you, could you tell me how I could change the collation of the newly created table to UTF-8?

Comment: ALTER TABLE accounts CHARACTER SET utf8

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean user account would have these columns.  Certainly they aren't all candidate keys.

No account ID?  Wouldn't that be the best unique primary key?

I can see where the columns you proposed would belong in a user/customer table; username and password (encrypted and salted, of course) would be in a credential table.  I wouldn't have any of these in an account table.  I'd have a foreign key pointing to the user that owned the account.